# Oneboxing for SO answers is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Seems like the short links obtained from the "link" button on answers has changed recently, and these new links (like https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350710/46642) are not considered by the oneboxing algorithm on chat. The full non-shortened links (like [<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350626/whats-the-meaning-of-and-when-applied-to-variable-names/3350710#3350710>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350626/whats-the-meaning-of-and-when-applied-to-variable-names/3350710#3350710)) still work though.

Would be nice if this could be fixed :)

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/772046#772046

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not convinced it's a good idea to have answer short URLs indistinguishable from the question ones, and we're considering changing that (of course, `/q/{id}` will continue to work either way, just as it did before; this is just about "what does the UI give you").

Anyhow, oneboxing answers with the new links works now.

Comment: You're a star! Can you now please look into the problem of `https` links to xkcd? `:)` After all, what's a chat full of geeks worth if they have a hard time linking to xkcd?

Comment: @sbi If a room full of geeks has a hard time deleting a character from a URL, I'm a little concerned

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: But it's just Not Right™ that this doesn't work! (And that's the C++ room we're from, and you know C++ programmers are anal.)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: It doesn't seem reasonable to require _anyone_ to selectively remove characters from a valid URL in order to get it to work.